# Am I using NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth and NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear improperly?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

everyone. I have a quick question regarding the use of `NSCalendar` and the constant `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` (and/or `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear`). I want to get a loop-able range of weeks in a certain month and year. I thought doing so would be quite straight-forward. Of course, however, it hasn't been. What am I doing wrong? Here's what I've got:

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfWeeksInMonth:(NSUInteger)month year:(NSUInteger)year
{
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    comps.month = month;
    comps.year = year;

    NSDate *date = [self.calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

    return [self.calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth // or ... WeekOfYear
                               inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth 
                              forDate:date];
}
```

I figured that if I input `month = 4` and `year = 2014`, the above method would return something like:

```
=> NSRange: {14, 5}
```

In other words, `14` would be the week number in the year and `5` would be the number of weeks in the month.

When using the `NSWeekCalendarUnit` constant, the above example output is exactly what I get. However, after checking out the constants in NSCalendar.h, `NSWeekCalendarUnit` has been deprecated as of OS X 10.9. Apple's docs don't mention it anywhere, but I generally take cues from the actual header files when it comes to working with stuff I'm not sure about.

Anyway, because I don't want to get behind in the times, I tried both `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` and `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear`, and the returned range for both is `{NSNotFound, NSNotFound}`. What's the deal? Anyone have a clue as to why Apple doesn't write documentation for this stuff?